# export and import a custom promise function not getting any results

Tags: javascript, import, async-await, promise, module

If I put everything in "scripts.js", it works, it logs out array of results in console `Array(5) [ "ok", "ok", "ok", "ok", "ok" ]`, but if I put the function in "utils.js" and import it into "scripts.js" to use, I get nothing in the console. **See below code:**

utils.js

```
const waitToLoadImgs = (imgEls) => {
  const imgElsPromise = imgEls.map((imgEl) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      imgEl.addEventListener("load", () => {
        return resolve("ok");
      });
    });
  });

  const allImgElsLoaded = Promise.all(imgElsPromise);
  return allImgElsLoaded;
};

export { waitToLoadImgs };
```

scripts.js

```
import {waitToLoadImgs} from "./utils.js";

const imgEls = [...document.querySelectorAll("img")];

const loadImgsResult = async()=>{
  const result = await waitToLoadImgs(imgEls);
  console.log(result); //<----- console empty, no result log out in console
}

loadImgsResult();
```

index.html

```
<body>
  <img src="./assets/recycle-bin-remove-icon.svg" />
  <img src="./assets/recycle-bin-remove-icon.svg" />
  <img src="./assets/recycle-bin-remove-icon.svg" />
  <img src="./assets/recycle-bin-remove-icon.svg" />
  <img src="./assets/recycle-bin-remove-icon.svg" />
  <script src="scripts.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

but if I put all js codes in one js file, I get the results in console. why am I not getting any results if I split my codes into two js files? what am I doing wrong?

**----------UPDATE----------**

I just found out there is one more problem, when I put all codes in one js file and console log out the results, chrome's dev tool console doesn't show the results but firfox's dev tool console does show the results array.....

Comment: It works. If you're not getting a console log it means not all the promises have resolved, -> not all of the listeners have been called -> not all the images have been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the image is loaded before you add the event listener.

Change the utils.js like this:

```
const waitToLoadImgs = (imgEls) => {
  const imgElsPromise = imgEls.map((imgEl) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      if(imgEl.complete){ resolve("before_ok");return; }
      imgEl.addEventListener("load", () => {
        return resolve("ok");
      });
    });
  });

  const allImgElsLoaded = Promise.all(imgElsPromise);
  return allImgElsLoaded;
};

export { waitToLoadImgs };
```

Comment: it logs out ```Array(5) [ "before_ok", "before_ok", "before_ok", "before_ok", "before_ok" ]```, I still don't quite get it, so I can't add "load" event to the img elements? I thought "load" event listener supposed to run after the img element is done loading?